# Is it idiomatic to say "to cut the thread off" (context: a thread sticks out of your clothes and you want to get rid of it)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Ok, look at the picture, there is a thread sticking out of your clothes and you want to get rid of it.

[image]

Is it idiomatic to say "**to cut the thread off**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. People will commonly say, "Oh, I've got to cut this thread off", or a little shorter, "I've got to cut this thread."

Comment: Could we also say "to trim the thread off"?

Comment: Sure. And there are many other words that would describe what you're doing. "Snip the thread", "lop off the loose thread", etc. Of course if you use words that are too unusual it might be confusing, but "cut" and "trim" and "snip" are all pretty common.